# Socket.io not connecting (2)

Tags: node.js, laravel, websocket, socket.io

I'm using Laravel and my directory structure is like below:

```
/example.com
    /server.js
    /node_modules
    /css
    /js
    /main/views/writemessage.blade.php
    /main/views/socket.blade.php
    /main/app/Http/Controllers/SocketController.php
```

my code in `server.js` is:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.set('origins', '*:*');
var redis = require('redis');
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

server.listen(8890);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log("new client connected");
  var redisClient = redis.createClient();
  redisClient.subscribe('message');

  redisClient.on("message", function(channel, message) {
    console.log("mew message in queue "+ message + "channel");
    socket.emit(channel, message);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('Disconnected!!!');
    redisClient.quit();
  });

});
```

my code in `writemessage.blade.php` is:

```
@extends('_template.default')
@section('main-content')
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" >
          <div id="messages" ></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('https://example.com:8890', {secure: true});
    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        console.log('YES!!!!!!!!!!');
        $( "#messages" ).append( "<p>"+data+"</p>" );
      });
</script>

@endsection
```

my code in `socket.blade.php` is:

```
@extends('_template.default')
@section('main-content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Send message</div>
                    <form action="sendmessage" method="POST">
                        <input type="text" name="message" >
                        <input type="submit" value="send">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

When I was in Windows it was returning `CORS` issues, but now when I'm using Linux it doesn't return that error but it doesn't return anything in console.
Also redis is running...but when I run `node server.js` it doesn't even print Connected nor Disconnected messages in console. Where my problem is from? Is it from url? I say url because when I check the Network Monitor in firefox I see that it is saying `The connection used to fetch this resource was not secure`. Have I done something wrong? Or should I do something more? How can test where the problem is from?

BTW my node version: 6.14.3 and my npm version: 3.10.10

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this reading can help: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-socketio-and-broadcasting-events-with-laravel-51

Comment: Thank you @Sangar82. When I created a new project and did exactly what your link said it worked partially. Socket.io and Laravel Echo working but not when using Private Channel. The error that returns is this:

Comment: `[13:11:15] - Sending auth request to: http://127.0.0.1/

? [13:11:15] - lrNd0To9WsF0y89LAAAB could not be authenticated to private-test-channel.1
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://127.0.0.1/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.26 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.7 Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>

Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 301`

Comment: Seems to be a connection problem.. In my develop environment I connnect like this: <code>var redis = new Redis();</code>  and in production, I must connect like this var <code>redis = new Redis(6379, 'my_private_ip', {no_ready_check: true});</code>